# expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled() error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using Enzyme/Jest to write a test for a function on my container hat is triggered through an onChange of a checkbox component. I'm attempting to simulate a 'change', however, somehow the 'change' is not triggering the onChange function to be called. Not sure what is going on here... I've tried to change the simulate to a 'click', removed the target object and it still did not work.

**Container**

```
export class Data extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data_list_api: [],
      selected_data: this.props.dataForm,
    };

  }

handleCheck = (event) => {
    const newSelectedData = Object.assign({}, this.state.selected_data);
    if (newSelectedData[event.target.name]) {
      delete newSelectedData[event.target.name];
    } else {
      newSelectedData[event.target.name] = [true, event.target.id];
    }
    this.setState({ selected_data: newSelectedData });
  }

render() {
    const dataOptions = this.state.data_list_api.map((val, index) => (
      <div className="form-group no-margin" key={index}>
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <div className="checkbox">
            <Checkbox
              name={val.data_name}
              id={val.data_id}
              onChange={this.handleCheck}
              checked={this.state.selected_datas[val.data_name] ? true : false}
              disabled={!this.state.selected_datas[val.data_name] && this.getObjectLength(this.state.selected_datas) > 3}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
       {dataOptions}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Test**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import { Data } from '../index';

function setup() {
  const props = {
    submitDataForm: jest.fn(),
  }
  const wrapper = shallow(<Data {...props} />);
  return { props, wrapper };
}

it('expects handleCheck to work', () => {
const { wrapper, props } = setup();

wrapper.setState({ data_list_api: [
  { data_name: 'data1 name',
    data_id: 123 },
  { data_name: 'data2 name',
    data_id: 234 },
  { data_name: 'data2  name',
    data_id: 345 }],
});

wrapper.instance().handleCheck = jest.fn();

wrapper.update();

wrapper.find('.checkbox').first().simulate('change', { target: { checked: true } });

expect(wrapper.instance().handleCheck).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();


});
```

**Error**

```
 expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected mock function to have been called.

  at Object.<anonymous> (app/containers/Schools/tests/index.test.js:95:44)
      at Promise (<anonymous>)
  at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:42:16)
      at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why not just test that the state has changed?

Comment: It won't work for me either, because the onChange function hasn't even been called. It seems like there's an issue with the "simulate change" portion, I don't get why it's not simulating the change (thereby not causing the onChange function to run, thereby not changing the state).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your selector `wrapper.find('.checkbox').first()`. This will trigger the event on `<div className="checkbox">`. But this element does not have the event listener, and `.simulate` does not behave like real events so it does not propagate. From the docs:

> Currently, event simulation for the shallow renderer does not
>   propagate as one would normally expect in a real environment. As a
>   result, one must call .simulate() on the actual node that has the
>   event handler set. Even though the name would imply this simulates an
>   actual event, .simulate() will in fact target the component's prop
>   based on the event you give it. For example, .simulate('click') will
>   actually get the onClick prop and call it.

To fix this you have to select the component that have the click handler attached:

```
wrapper.find('Checkbox')
```